# Space efficient way to store and read massive 3d dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, pytorch, storage

I am trying to train a neural network on sequential data. My dataset will consist of 3.6 million training examples. Each example will be a 30 x 32 ndarray (32 features observed over 30 days).

My question is what is the most space-efficient way to write and read this data?

Essentially it will have shape `(3.6m, 30, 32)` and `np.save()` seems convenient but I can't hold this whole thing in memory so I can't really save it using `np.save()` (or load it back using `np.load()`). CSV also won't work because my data has 3 dimensions.

My plan to create the thing is to process entries in batches and append them to some file so that I can keep memory free as I go.

Eventually, I am going to use the data file as an input for a PyTorch IterableDataset so it must be something that can be loaded one line at a time (like a `.txt` file, but I'm hoping there is some better way to save this data that is more true to its tabular, 3-dimensional nature). Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you should use a dedicated storage system, so this question is basically asking which one, and that's basically off topic for SO. Instead, you should search around for something that matches your criteria. In the past, for similar problems, I've found that [HDF5](https://www.h5py.org/) works well; but an ordinary database storing compressed arrays might also work and have different costs/benefits; and there are many other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have read some about HDF5 and it seems like it might be what I need. I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: Doesn't `pytorch` have a means of defining a model, and feading data, for training and testing, as batches?  I've seen people defining `tensors` with a shape like `(None, 30, 32)` where the `None` denotes a 'virtual' dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are planning on using an iterable dataset you shouldn't need random access (`IterableDataset` doesn't support shuffle samplers). In that case, why not just write everything to a binary file and iterate over that? I find in practice this often is much faster than alternative solutions. This should be much faster than saving as a text file since you avoid the overhead of converting text to numbers.

An example implementation may look something like the following. First we could build a binary file as follows (containing random data as a placeholder)

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

filename = 'data.bin'
num_samples = 3600000
rows, cols = 30, 32
dtype = np.float32

# format: <num_samples> <rows> <cols> <sample0> <sample1>...
with open(filename, 'wb') as fout:
    # write a header that contains the total number of samples and the rows and columns per sample
    fout.write(np.array((num_samples, rows, cols), dtype=np.int32).tobytes())
    for i in tqdm(range(num_samples)):
        # random placeholder
        sample = np.random.randn(rows, cols).astype(dtype)
        # write data to file
        fout.write(sample.tobytes())
```

Then we could define an `IterableDataset` as follows

```py
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset, DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm

def binary_reader(filename, start=None, end=None, dtype=np.float32):
    itemsize = np.dtype(dtype).itemsize
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
        num_samples, rows, cols = np.frombuffer(fin.read(3 * np.dtype(np.int32).itemsize), dtype=np.int32)
        start = start if start is not None else 0
        end = end if end is not None else num_samples
        blocksize = itemsize * rows * cols
        start_offset = start * blocksize
        fin.seek(start_offset, 1)
        for _ in range(start, end):
            yield np.frombuffer(fin.read(blocksize), dtype=dtype).reshape(rows, cols).copy()


class BinaryIterableDataset(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, filename, start=None, end=None, dtype=np.float32):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.dtype = dtype

    def __iter__(self):
        return binary_reader(self.filename, self.start, self.end, self.dtype)
```

From a quick test of this dataset on my system (which uses SSD storage) I find I am able to iterate over all 3.6 million samples in about 10 seconds

```py
dataset = BinaryIterableDataset('data.bin')
for sample in tqdm(dataset):
    pass
```

```
3600000it [00:09, 374026.17it/s]
```

Using a `DataLoader` with `batch_size=256` it takes me about 20 seconds to iterate over the whole dataset (converting to tensors and creating batches has some overhead). For this dataset I found that the overhead of transferring data to and from shared memory when using parallel loading is actually quite a bit slower than just using 0 workers. Therefore I recommend using `num_workers=0`. As with any iterable dataset you would need to add extra logic to support num_workers > 1, though I'm not sure it would be worth it in this case.

```py
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=256, num_workers=0)
for batch in tqdm(loader):
    # batch is a tensor of shape (256, 30, 32)
    pass
```

```
14063it [00:19, 710.49it/s]
```

Note that the `data.bin` file would not be portable across systems that use different byte order. Though modifications could be made to support that.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Just one clarifying question: how does `np.buffer(fin.read(3*4), dtype=np.int32)` give the number of data points, rows, and columns? Would this be the case always or does this depend on the shape of my particular data?

Comment: @thehumaneraser It comes down to the format of the binary file that we create. When building the file, the line `fout.write(np.array((num_samples, rows, cols), dtype=np.int32).tobytes())` writes the number of samples, rows, and columns as int32 at the start of the file. To read these back we need to read a buffer of size 3 times the size of int32 (4 bytes) so 3*4. Maybe it would be more clear if I wrote this as `np.buffer(fin.read(3*np.dtype(np.int32).itemsize), dtype=np.int32)`?

Comment: Keep in mind we aren't using a pre-defined file format, we are directly writing and reading a binary file that suites our specific needs. We could write it however we want as long as we write the reading code to match the format we wrote.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for that clear explanation and for your elegant solution, which will save me hours on this project and no doubt help me in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @thehumaneraser After considering it for a while I think a memory mapped solution may be even more applicable. I added another answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to use memory mapped tensors. This is similar to the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64408076/2790047) but is better IMO since it abstracts away the direct interaction with binary data and operates at a higher level of abstraction.

Every tensor stores its data using a `Storage` object. This mechanism allows us to define a memory mapped storage system using [`FloatStorage.from_file`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/storage.html#torch.FloatStorage.from_file). Using a memory mapped tensor allows us to both write our dataset to disk and read it as if it were a normal tensor of shape (3600000, 32, 30) without directly storing that memory in RAM.

For example we could write our dataset to disk using something like the following

```py
import torch

filename = 'data.bin'
num_samples = 3600000
rows, cols = 32, 30

# shared=True allows us to save the tensor to disk as we perform in place modifications to it
samples = torch.FloatTensor(torch.FloatStorage.from_file(filename, shared=True, size=num_samples * rows * cols)).reshape(num_samples, rows, cols)

for idx in tqdm(range(num_samples)):
    # placeholder random samples, insert your actual samples here
    # every in-place assignment to samples is automatically reflected on the disk
    samples[idx] = torch.randn(rows, cols)
```

This has the benefit of being compatible with the built-in [`TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset)

```py
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

filename = 'data.bin'
num_samples = 3600000
rows, cols = 32, 30

# shared=False prevents changes to samples from affecting the data on disk
samples = torch.FloatTensor(torch.FloatStorage.from_file(filename, shared=False, size=num_samples * rows * cols)).reshape(num_samples, rows, cols)

dataset = TensorDataset(samples)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=256, num_workers=0)

for batch in tqdm(loader):
    # batch is a (256, 32, 30) tensor
    pass
```

```
100%|██████████| 14063/14063 [00:11<00:00, 1216.80it/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `np.save`:

```
np.save('data.npy', x)
retrieved_array = np.load('data.npy')
```

You could use:

```
np.savez_compressed('data.npz', array=x)
retrieved_array = np.load('data.npz')['array']
```

It helped to reduce size of data from 375MB to 60MB on my laptop on this data:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,10, size=(30, 32, 100000))
```

Remark1: note that this is not time efficient:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,10, size=(30,32,10000))
%timeit np.save('data.npy', x)
%timeit np.load('data.npy')
%timeit np.savez_compressed('data.npz', array=x)
%timeit np.load('data.npz')['array']

153 ms ± 42.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
35.7 ms ± 3.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.57 s ± 209 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
163 ms ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not get around the original problem. While maybe allowing me to write data to this file in batches, I would still have to load the whole file to later access that data and it certainly won't produce an iterator

Comment: It depends a lot whether your data is sparse. If it is, you can use smth like `np.nonzero` to store coordinates of nonzero cells only. If it's not, I'm afraid I can't help here because `numpy` works in a quite optimal way itself.

Comment: Unfortunately my data is not sparse except for the occasional odd 0 for a missing data point (which is pretty rare). But thank you for your comments, I'll try to post a solution once I figure out what will work