# Pytorch Tensors using all RAM

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a list of tensors, which is too heavy for my RAM. I would like to save them in filesystem and load them when needed

```
torch.save(single_tensor, 'tensor_<idx>.pt')
```

If I want to use batches while training, is there an automatic way to load tensors when needed?
I was thinking about using `TensorDataset` and `DataLoader`, but since now I don't have tensors in a list but in filesystem, how should I build them?

Comment: You could use a memory mapped tensor. I.e. instead of the tensor being stored in RAM it is stored on disk but can be accessed like a normal tensor. You can copy over pieces of it to RAM when needed via index. There's not a lot of good information on this in the docs unfortunately but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64408659/2790047) will help.

Comment: I don't know if I understood well: I create this binary file, initially empty. Then I iterate through it writing down all the tensors. Once I wrote everything I can wrap this object inside a TensorDataset, right?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a custom Dataset class, overriding the `__getitem__` method. In this method I would load the tensor of a given index via `torch.load()`. Could this be a solution?

Comment: Yes that would work, you could save each tensor as a separate file and load the specific one during `__getitem__`.  The alternative I was suggesting was to create a single big tensor as a memory mapped tensor, then provide it to a `TensorDataset` as described in that answer I linked. That link I provided describes how to create a memory mapped tensor and also how to load it again as a read-only (shared=False) tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly save the tensors one by one to file with `torch.save()`

```py
torch.save(tensor, 'path/to/file.pt')
```

Then this `Dataset` class allows to load the tensors only when they are really needed:

```py
class EmbedDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, first_embed_path, second_embed_path, labels):
        self.first_embed_path = first_embed_path 
        self.second_embed_path = second_embed_path 
        self.labels = labels

        

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self, i):

        label = self.labels[i]

        embed = torch.load(os.path.join(self.first_embed_path, str(i) + '.pt'))

        pos = torch.load(os.path.join(self.second_embed_path, str(i) + '.pt'))

        tensor = torch.cat((embed, pos))

        return tensor, label
```

Here the tensors are named with numbers, eg `1.pt` or `1816.pt`